# C++ matching a specific string

Tags: c++

I have a function here that checks a text file for the existence of a string. The problem I have right now is that it's checking for substrings, so if the file has the word "IronMan" and any part of that string will pass the check.

Here's my code for the function:

```
void UIFunctions::checkIfExists()
{
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        getline(fin, line);
        if (line.compare(getFriendName()) == string::npos)
        {
            setExists(false);
            cout << getExistsErrorPrompt() << endl << endl;
            if (listAfterCheck == 1)
            {
                listUsers();
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << getErrorPrompt();
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for solutions and read that line.**compare** (changed from line.**find**) is what I need to match entire strings but instead of accepting substrings (like line.find did) now it doesn't accept anything at all to pass the check.

Edit: Also the file that this function uses would look something like this:

```
Ironman Captain Thor
```

Comment: Why not use regular expressions?

Comment: Like "if (line == getFriendName())"? I'll try it. Edit: doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern `while (!fin.eof())` use `while (getline(fin, line))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are assuming that [`compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns the same value as [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) would. The `compare` function returns an integer with value:

- `0` if the strings are equal
- `>0` if the *compared* string (in your case `line`) is lexicographically first
- `<0` if the *comparing* string (in your case `getFriendName()`) is lexicographically first

Therefore to check for an exact match, you would want:

```
if(line.compare(getFriendName()) == 0) {
    setExists(false);
    // ...
}
```

Comparing the result of `compare` with `string::npos` will never trigger since the magnitude of `compare` is the first differing character between your two strings.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::basic_string::compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) returns a value less than 0, 0 or more than 0.  Since

```
if (line.compare(getFriendName()) == string::npos)
```

Is seeing if the return is the maximum value of the type of `string::npos` you more than likely will never trigger the if statement.  If you only want to match a string exactly then you can use

```
if (line == getFriendName())
```

If instead you want to find any line that starts with `getFriendName()` then you want

```
if (line.find(getFriendName()) == 0)
```

In the above `find` will only return `0` if the string starts with what you want.